# How to use breakpoints to write to a file

Tags: ios, xcode, shell, breakpoints

[image]

Execution stops on breakpoint, but there is no any text files in my home folder. What am I doing wrong?
Thanks for answer.

Comment: uncheck `wait until done`? Good luck.

Comment: @shellter It's not solve my issue(

Comment: You can try creating the file manually before debugging. Or change the path to /tmp/?

Comment: @NulledPointer Same result when I create the file manually. I also try to create the file via breakpoints using "touch", it works but file is empty.